# Removing rust from my jacket

Tags: stain

My jacket's got some rust stains on it, I searched online and read about trying vinegar, I soaked it in vinegar for 30 mins approx, but it didn't do a thing.

I read about some products like `Iron Out` or some oxyclean thingy, I don't have any commercial products where I live.

It's a new jacket and I'd hate it if the rust stain stayed on it.

Comment: Can you add some picture of these rust stains?

Comment: As a preliminary step, go over it with a lint roller - those rolls of adhesive tape with a handle sticking off one end. That may pick up a significant amount of the rust, if it's not soaked in. It probably won't get _all_ the rust but you should notice a difference.

Answer (score 1):

"Elbow grease" can help, i.e. scrubbing. An old toothbrush makes a good tool for scrubbing gently, but *persistently*, with vinegar, or better yet, citric acid (also sold as *[sour salt](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01DP9BZ1U)* in the baking section of groceries). *[Lestoil](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0036B89US)* might also help.

Be careful not to scrub so much that it raises the nap of the fabric.

Answer (score 1):

Normal bleach or oxygen products like Oxyclean won't remove rust; in fact, they'll make it worse.

If you don't have access to "Iron Out", oxalic acid will convert the rust into a soluble form that comes out with ordinary detergents.  Pretreat the stain, wait until it's no longer visible, then wash with bleach-free detergent.  That should cover it.